# Center div vertically in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

How can I center a `div` vertically in bootstrap 5?
It should be aligned in the middle between of content before the `div` and the screen end.

Tried this:

```html
    <div>some content</div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div>div that should be centered</div>
    </div>
```

It makes the pages longer than it actually is. The div doesn´t looks centered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

- Wrap everything with one `div` that has 100% screen width and height.
- Use `flex-grow-1` for the second `div` so it takes the remaining height and center everything inside.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100 min-vw-100">
      <div>This div is not centered.</div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div>This div is centered.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you add some "lorem ipsum" at the beginning of the body you´ll see the problem

Comment: I updated my answer with one `div` in the beginning of the body. Check it.

Comment: The scrollbar showed up now. If the first div has 25% height for example, the second div won't be shown in the middle, because scrollable space is added below

Comment: Well of course. You added `min-vh-100` to do second div that wraps centered div. It means that second div height will have minimum value of screen height. Is your desired behavior to have both divs, but not scroll?

Comment: The second div should be centered vertically between the content above and the end of the page

Comment: I see. I updated my answer. Can you check it again?

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <style>
      .card
      {
        min-width: 320px;
        width: 480px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center vh-100">
    <div class="card shadow-lg">
      <div class="card-header text-bg-danger">
        <h2>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
          Login
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <form action="">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="email" class="form-label">Email address</label>
            <input
              placeholder="your registered email"
              class="form-control"
              type="email"
              name="email"
              id="email"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
            <input
              placeholder="your password"
              class="form-control"
              type="password"
              name="password"
              id="password"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
            <button class="btn btn-danger">Login</button> &nbsp;
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary">Reset all</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/266b76cb57.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```